# Chrome - Layout changes when I refresh the page if the browser is bigger

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a site which looks fine in firefox. I switched to chrome for testing and ive found something really weird.

If the browser window is wide enough everything looks fine. Once the page has loaded, if I then resize the window so its smaller, again everything is fine. However if once the window is smaller than the page's width, I THEN refresh the page, the layout is screwed up. Then If i make the window larger (without refreshing) the layout is not fixed, until I refresh the page.

Also, im looking a page now. Im not resizing it, im just clicking refresh and each time the site alternates between the correct and messed up layout.

I have no idea why this is happening as the site is very simple html and css site. Their is no content management system or javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Any examples? What's the URL?

Comment: Ive just uploaded it and now its always the incorrect layout, so i guess fixing this cross browser issue is a separate question. Maybe its some weird caching issue on my computer? The exact same files ive uploaded are still doing it on my computer when their local. Thanks. http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/ppp/advanced-search.html